# Possibility of dissipating 20 W via Nichrome wire safely

Tags: resistors, power-dissipation, dissipation

I am looking to use 1 foot (0.3 meters) of 32 AWG nichrome wire to dissipate roughly 20 watts of power. Assuming the wire was submersed in still transformer oil, would I be able to do this without melting the nichrome?

Comment: It depends on the design of convection flow of circulating oil. and power density of course but thermal conductance is high.  You can use vegetable oil for less smell.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Assuming it is just sitting in still transformer oil, will it likely melt?

Comment: How long is the wire?

Comment: @EasyOhm 1 foot long (0.3 meters)

Comment: have you tested it with water?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 No, nothing tested yet. I assume you mean distilled water?

Comment: I get that you have about 200 mm^2 area, or about 0.1W per mm^2.  That works out to evaporating 44 micrograms of water per mm^2 per second if dropped into normal water.  I don't think the wire will melt.

Comment: If you're heating oil, you might be better with a 30+ W rated resistor that's compatible with your oil.

Comment: What's wrong with air cooling, and why not just use a high power wirewound resistor?

Comment: I would worry that if the heat transfer is not enough fast, the region near to wire may change into something different and may cause a thermal runaway.

Comment: Outgassing could above flash point should cause thermal resistance to rise and runaway

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you for your advice, do you know of any other ways that I might be able to make my own 10 ohm 20 W resistor that can withstand 60 kV DC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to ball park this to see if it's reasonable to use only 12" of such thin wire dissipating 20W:

The surface area of your AWG32 wire is \$\pi \cdot \text {(0.008")} \cdot\$12" = 0.3\$\text{in}^2\$, so the watt density is 67W/\$\text{in}^2\$.

[Maximum recommended watt density](https://www.process-heating.com/articles/85942-do-not-overlook-watt-density) for vegetable oil with operating temperature of 400°F is 30W\$\text{in}^2\$, and even less for lubricating oils with 250°F operating temperature (more like 13-23W\$\text{in}^2\$) so I would say that you are likely well above the maximum watt density for reliable operation using transformer mineral oil.

You would be better off using a commercial cartridge heater with a much lower watt density (much more surface area but similar wattage).

Answer (score 1):

The value of flash point for transformer oil( mineral oil) is generally 140°C.  This is the lowest temperature where vapours can ignite.

The melting point of NiCr is > 1200'C.

If you wanted to a 25W dummy load, use a tungsten halogen bulb.  If you wantedto heat oil, do it externally.

**Heating wire this thin may be explosive exceeding the flash point.**